# Need to count how many records were return for an id, codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a votes table that holds votes. I need to get the amount of votes each user has in the table based on their id and then sort the query by who has the most votes. Basically a leaders table. How would I do that?

Comment: What does your table/data look like?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: `$query->num_records()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your table that stores all the votes is called `activity`, it stores the `id` and `user_id`.

Getting the vote totals:

```
select user_id, count(user_id) as votes from activity group by user_id;
```

Get the top 5 vote getters:

```
select user_id, count(user_id) as votes from activity group by user_id ORDER BY votes desc LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you sir!

Comment: `ORDER BY user_id` doesn't give the top 5. It should be `ORDER BY COUNT(user_id)` or `ORDER BY votes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(user_id) AS total_votes');
$this->db->from('votes');
$this->db->group_by('user_id');
$this->db->order_by('total_votes DESC');
$result = $this->db->get()->result();
```